# ¿Cómo ajustar tablas en PDF de Dompdf?

Tags: php, pdf, zend

Estoy usando DOMPDF y genero tablas grandes con contenido extenso.

¿Hay manera en que todo quede dentro de una sola hoja sin salir de los márgenes, aunque el contenido se haga más pequeño?
Este contenido puede variar, y es necesario que todo quede dentro de la misma hoja.

Comment: ¡Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! ☺ No olvides visitar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más acerca de este sitio. Realmente necesitas incluir más detalles en tu pregunta para que la comunidad pueda responder satisfactoriamente. En el [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) encontrarás [*¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [*Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Puedes editar tu pregunta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/40381/edit).

Comment: al parecer esto no es posible usando funciones de la librería [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29969198/4987172)

Comment: Puedes intentar un condicional que te determine a partir de la cantidad de filas de tus datos el tamaño de la fuente, deberás hacer algunas pruebas para establecer la relación (cada cuantos registros deberás reducir el tamaño de tu fuente)

Answer (score 1):

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_option('dpi', 256);
```

Puedes configurar la resolución en las opciones de Dompdf con el comnado 
 `set_option`

para ajustar el contenido en la hoja.